# Add page specific CSS to 1 single page in Magento 2.2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, css, magento2.2.2, less

I have 1 specific page in Magento 2.2.2, that I'd like CSS on. In my _extend.less file, if I include the CSS there, it'll effect other pages that have the same classes. I don't want that to happen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve this :

1. Go to that page & Inspect element.
2. Search for body tag, right click on body tag - select 'copy selector' under 'copy' option.
3. In _extend.less, paste the copied selector let's say selector be- body.question-page new-topbar

`body.question-page new-topbar{
// write your css inside
}`

4. compile and run grunt to update changes.
5. Test it.

Comment: I tried that, it still loads on every other page. Is there another way?